# Regular Expression to match the following Date Format

Tags: regex

I have a regex to match the date formats `Sep.23'15` or `Sep 23'15` or `Sep23'15`

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}[. ]\d{2}'\d{2}
```

I am able to match `Sep.23'15` & `Sep 23'15` but not `Sep23'15`

How to write the regex to match with space and without space ?

Comment: Use `?` for `[. ]`. **Answer:** `[a-zA-Z]{3}[. ]?\d{2}'\d{2}`

Comment: Thanks, Working Fine. @Tushar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest matching a dot (optionally) and then use `*` quantifier instead of the `?` [suggested by Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350005/regular-expression-to-match-the-following-date-format#comment56441609_34350005) applied to a space:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}\.?[ ]*\d{2}'\d{2}
           ^^^^^^^
```

This regex will also handle format like `Sep. 23'15`  (with a dot *and* a space(s) between the month and the day'year).

**Regex explanation:**

- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` - 3 ASCII letters
- `\.?` - 1 or 0 dots
- `[ ]*` - zero or more regular spaces (`\h`, or `\p{Zs}`, or `[[:blank:]]` are recommended depending on the regex flavor if you only need to match *horizontal* whitespace)
- `\d{2}'\d{2}` - 2 digits + `'` + 2 digits.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV6rX4/2)

Comment: you use `*` (incorrect, as it allows `Sep.......23'15` as valid) but `?` (correct) in your demo... why?

Comment: @LuisColorado: I am curious why that happened myself. I took into account your remark and reconsidered my answer to better express my approach.

Comment: :)  now I upvote your answer, despite it allows to use both, like `Sep,     23'15` (with several blanks after the dot)  better would be `(\.|[ ]*)`  which allows either one dot or a sequence of `0` or more spaces, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
[A-Za-z]{3}[\.\s]?\d{1,2}\'\d{2}
```

Comment: A dot inside a character class already matches a literal `.` symbol, no need escaping it. Also, OP might not want to match any whitespace (`\s` also matches newline symbols).